# Xcode 15.2 - Issues with mixed ObjC and Swift Codebase

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, autocomplete

I have an older project with a mixed ObjC + Swift codebase. I'm in the process of converting everything to Swift in the hopes that Xcode will work better again when the Codebase is not mixed anymore.

This is an example of the issues I'm currently facing:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode Autocomplete]

The class `IVMapViewController` is defined in ObjC and the property `mapViewModel` is declared in the ObjC Header fine. The ObjC Header file is included in the bridging header. I'm trying to access the property `mapViewModel` in an swift extension on the same class.

I can actually compile & run the code just fine, but Xcode Autocompletion does not work, and Xcode generates "Phantom" errors in the Issue Navigator (those errors also stay there when a build completes successful)

On the other hand, if I put an actual error in the code, compilation fails, but the actual error will NOT show up in the Issue Navigator. I'll have to dig through the build log to find the actual error.

Am I doing anything wrong? Do I need to adjust some project setting?

Comment: Clean/Remove derived data? When converting code, there is sometimes some old cache for the compiler...

Comment: It looks like the particular issue in your screen cap is caused by you defining a local variable that shadows the property `mapViewModel`.

Comment: @Larme I've removed derived data / cleaned and rebuilt the project many times already

Comment: @JeremyP hm good point, but that code was actually just to illustrate the issue. All those lines above 187 in my screencapture were just attempts to break it down into several smaller steps to help out the compiler and see where it goes wrong. Initially I've attempted to directly access a property of `mapViewModel` inside a closure.